# Many-to-many in laravel combine with where

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have many to many relationship between the models KSMschema and NORM

```
$normen = Ksmheader::find(15)->norms;

foreach($norms as $item){
                     echo $item->number;

                 }
```

Now i get a list of norms. This is one example:

```
[{"id":18,"certificaten_id":5,"nummer":"1.2.3","text":"Text van nog een norm.","created_at":"2014-02-14 15:14:05","updated_at":"2014-02-14 15:14:20","deleted_at":null,"pivot":{"ksmheader_id":9,"norm_id":18}}
```

But now i also need to sort them on a second column 'column_id'

```
$normen = Ksmheader::find(15)->normen->where('certificates_id', '=', 6);
```

This does not seem to work. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your first exemple you use "norms" has your relation name, and in the second exemple your use "normen"?

Comment: use parenthesis if you want to chain normen()->where ... not normen->  and read this http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#dynamic-properties, and consider seblaze answer about calling correct method

Comment: I changed it. Normen is dutch. I converted the example to english "norms" (after testing) so you guys could understand. That is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you are using the correct function to get the norms :

```
Ksmheader::find(15)->norms->where('certificates_id', '=', 6);
```

What error/exception do you get if you try the above code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanx all for you suggestions. I just found the answer myself.
For anyone who wants to know:
I first added the () after 'normen'. Just as  deczo suggested.
Then i added a ->get()

```
normen = Ksmheader::find($ksmSchemaRow->ksmheader_id)->normen()->where('certificaten_id', '=', 5)->get();

foreach($normen as $item){
                     echo $item->nummer;
                  //echo 'NAME';
                      echo '/';
                 }
```

I added get() now i get the results i want.